# I want to delete the token in d[24]

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to displace the token in d[24] with " ". Can anybody help me. Thanks

```
:1 > d = "01-04-2013 ist the first-day of April"
  => "01-04-2013 ist the first-day of April" 
:2 > d.index(/(\D|\s)(\/|\-|\:|\#|\\|\"|\'){1,}/)+1
  => 24
:3 > d[d.index(/(\D|\s)(\/|\-|\:|\#|\\|\"|\'){1,}/)+1]
  => "-"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the character your expression is finding the index of, just assign `' '` to it;

> irb(main):001:0> **d = "01-04-2013 ist the first-day of April"**
>   => "01-04-2013 ist the first-day of April"
>   irb(main):002:0> **d[d.index(/(\D|\s)(/|-|\:|#|\|\"|\'){1,}/)+1] = ' '**
>   => " "
>   irb(main):003:0> **d**
>   => "01-04-2013 ist the first day of April"

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I get your question but wouldn't

```
d[24] = " "
```

work?